# Interface 'JestImportMeta' incorrectly extends interface 'ImportMeta'

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm migrating from jest v27 to v29 and encounter this error:

```bash
node_modules/@jest/environment/build/index.d.ts:329:26 - error TS2430: Interface 'JestImportMeta' incorrectly extends interface 'ImportMeta'.
  The types returned by 'jest.createMockFromModule(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.

329 export declare interface JestImportMeta extends ImportMeta {
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in node_modules/@jest/environment/build/index.d.ts:329
```

This error occurs when trying to compile using `tsc`.

Related packages in my package.json:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.0.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.0"
}
```

Versions:

- NodeJs `v16.15.1`
- npm `v8.11.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the bug might be reintroduced in jest 29.4.x. To resolve this I did:
`yarn upgrade jest@~29.2.0 @types/jest@~29.2.0`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to update `tsconfig.json` to have this line under the object `compilerOptions`:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

It needed to know to use node types specifically

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the types which was fixed in jest v29.1.0 and @types/jest v29.0.3
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/13199#issuecomment-1260897649

Answer (score 0):

I have the following version of `jest` and `@types/jest` and all is the well. `tsc` works well too

```
"@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
"jest": "^29.6.4",
```